# Testing Plaid Update Mode

Tags: plaid

I am trying to test update mode in the sandbox. I currently have a "chase" account set up, which of course brings up the platypus oauth UI. When I create a plaid link in update mode, I get an option to select the bank accounts. I thought the default was to NOT allow the users to select new accounts because the default to account_selection_enabled is False.
Is this just a limitation to the Sandbox? Or is it a limitation to OAuth?
I'm wondering if I need to handle new accounts coming from the update call? Our code currently only allows a single bank account to be set up, and I'd rather they delete the account, and relink to a different account, if they want to change accounts.

But if there is no way to prevent it from the OAuth case, I'll have to handle this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

For OAuth institutions, `account_selection_enabled` will always act as though it is `true`. This is a recent change and the docs have not yet been updated to reflect it. I believe it is technically possible for a user to change their selected account in this way while going through Update Mode. If this occurs, you should be able to detect it via a change in the `account_id` and/or `mask`.

Comment: I think I can handle the account change, but I was filtering accounts before, only allowing checking or savings. I can't set the account filtering unless account_selection_enabled is True. So, unfortunately, it sounds like I am going to have to set this to True, always, so I can set the account filter. I think that I can check if the institution is oAuth, but that is an additional call now.